# jQuery get attribute out of style

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I need to extract something out of the "style" attribute: the "top" and "left" attribute

```
<div style="top: 250px; left: 250px;" id="1" class="window ui-draggable">
```

What's the best way of doing this with jQuery? Is there an easy way, or will I have to resort to string functions?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

It depends what you need. If you need the computed value - e.g. the actual value the browser used after parsing all the style sheets - use

```
$("#element_1").css("top")
$("#element_1").css("left")
```

If it's a pixel value, that is always going to be the one specified in the `style` property - *unless* that was overridden by an `!important` statement in a style sheet.

[jQuery docs for `.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

If you *explicitly* need the value specified in the element's `style` property, use

```
$("#element_1")[0].style.top
$("#element_1")[0].style.left
```

unlike `.css()`, these values will be empty if they were not specified in the `style` property.

(Using ID `element_1`, you can't have an ID named `1`)

Comment: Just to make sure: Will accessing the properties through the element's style object *also* return the computed value?

Comment: @Tomalak no, `style`  will give you the value explicitly specified in `style=` only.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`CSS`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) function:

```
var topValue = $(this).css("top"); //Change the selector to meet your needs
var leftValue = $(this).css("left"); //Change the selector to meet your needs
```

Answer (score 2):

using .css() will return an integer + px, but you can easily get a nice clean integer by doing this:

```
var yourVar = parseInt($('selector').css('top'), 10);
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS properties are accessible through standard DOM properties:

```
alert( $("#theElement")[0].style.top ) // "250px"
alert( $("#theElement")[0].style.left ) // "250px"
```

As an aside, `"1"` is not a valid HTML element ID.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.getComputedStyle